# sum of maximal family of mutually orthogonal projections in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $e$ be a projection in $M$. Let $\{p_i\}_i$ be a maximal
family of mutually orthogonal projections in $M$ such that $p_i \preceq e$ for every $i$. Then I want to show that $\displaystyle \sum_i p_i$ is the central support of $e$.

Let $z=\displaystyle \sum_i p_i$. Then in order to show that $z$ is the central support of $e$ it's enough to show $z \in M'\cap M$ and $z$ is the smallest projection such that $ze=e.$ Please help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: @QuantumSpace for any two projections $p,q$ on a Hilbert space $p\le q$ and $qp=p$ are equivalent I think. So your definition and mine are equivalent, I think. Ah sorry, in your definition maybe you want to say $p\le e$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=\sum_jp_j$. By the comparison theorem, there exists $q$ central with
$$\tag1
q (1-z)\preceq qe,\qquad\qquad (1-q)e\preceq(1-q)(1-z).
$$
If $q(1-z)\ne0$ we contradict the maximally of $\{p_j\}$. So $q\leq z$. Then
$$\tag2
(1-q)e\preceq (1-q)(1-z)=1-z.
$$
This forces $(1-q)e=0$, for otherwise we again contradict the maximality. So $e≤q$. Then
$$\tag3
e≤z.$$ Let $r≤z-q$. By comparison there exists central $q'$ with
$$\tag4
q' (1-r)\preceq q'e.
$$
As $q'(1-r)\perp z$, this once more contradicts the maximality if nonzero; thus $q'≤r$. We also have
$$\tag5
(1-q')e\preceq (1-q')(1-r)=1-r,
$$
and the maximality of $\{p_j\}$ gives us $(1-q')e=0$, that is $e≤q'$. But then
$$\tag6
e≤q'≤r\perp q,
$$
contradicting $e≤q$. This shows that $r=0$ and so $z=q$.

At this stage we have that $z$ is central and $e≤z$. Let $z'$ be the central support of $e$. So $e≤z'≤z$. Then $z''=z-z'$ is central and $z''e=0$. Then $e≤1-z''$; as $1-z''\perp z$, the maximality forces $z''=0$, that $z'=z$. So $z$ is the central support of $e$.

Comment: This is very nice. But I am unable to understand how $q(1-z)\ne 0$ contradicts the maximally of $\{p_j\}$?

Comment: If $q(1-z)\ne0$, you have a projection that is below $e$ and is orthogonal to all the  $p_j$.

Comment: May be its trivial, but can you please say me what is the projection which is below $e$ and is orthogonal to all $p_j$. I thought its $q(1-z)$ itself but not able to see below $e$.

Comment: "Below" as in $q(1-z)\preceq e$ , which is the property you used to define the $p_j$. The family $\{p_j\}\cup\{q(1-z)\}$ is larger than $\{p_j\}$.